# Непонятный мусор в итоговой разметке

Tags: vue.js

После инициализации приложения в итоговой разметке содержится много мусора. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему это происходит и как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> По умолчанию атрибуты из родительской области видимости, которые не были распознаны как входные параметры, будут «проваливаться» и применяться к корневому элементу дочернего компонента как обычные HTML-атрибуты. При создании компонента, который оборачивает элемент или другой компонент, это не всегда может быть ожидаемым поведением. Устанавливая `inheritAttrs` в `false`, это поведение по умолчанию может быть отключено. Атрибуты доступны через свойство экземпляра `$attrs` (также добавленное в версии 2.4.0) и могут быть явно привязаны к некорневому элементу с использованием `v-bind`.

[`inheritAttrs`](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#inheritAttrs)

Comment: бывает и такое)

Answer (score 1):

Так происходит, когда в компонент передаются параметры, которые он не ожидает. Чтобы от этого избавиться, либо не передавайте то, что компоненту не нужно, либо же в `props` укажите те лишние переменные

```js
Vue.component('Child',{
  template:"<div>Child</div>"
})
Vue.component('Child2',{
  props:['another', 'test'],
  template:"<div>Child2</div>"
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <Child :test="{111:222}" :another="{111:222}"></Child>
  <Child2 :test="{111:222}" :another="{111:222}"></Child2>
</div>
```

Итог:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]